# Render Image is further back than viewport image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, interface, camera, workflow

I am new to blender (yes, laugh at the obligatory doughnut) and I when I set up the camera (I use NUM 0 to access the camera and move it into position with "Lock camera to view") in the viewport it shows as the first attached image, but when I render it the image is further back as shown in the second image. Is this normal behavior or am I missing something?
[image: Viewport]

[image: Render View]

Comment: Have you done anything to change the focal length of your camera? If not, try repositioning the camera to your preferred view with Ctrl+Alt+Num0 (snap camerra to viewport perspective)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I did play around with it to try and fix this but I have since set it back to what I believe is default, 50mm. Is this the correct length?

Comment: Yeah, 50mm is default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: View with active area]

In this first image, you can see a dark grey border around the plane and torus. Is border represents the edges of the render camera's view. I don't see this in your top image, which leads me to believe you're zoomed in like the second image.[image: Zoomed view] Notice in this view the camera has not moved, that is, both pictures will render the same, but you can no longer see the safe area because you have 'zoomed in' on the render area.

To see the whole render area press <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: Yes this does seem to be the case. When I tap NUM 5 that view is what I end up getting from the render and it is zoomed out. Pardon my ignorance, but do you know how I can zoom back out in the viewport? Mousing out zooms out the viewport and render cameras.

Comment: Turn off  "Lock camera to view" and scroll wheel. (and you can upvote and accept the answer as well.)

Comment: Aha, that was it! Thank you so much and your answer is now marked :)

Comment: press "home" to see the whole picture in the image editor window.

Comment: Thanks @susu added that to the answer, and my own list of favorite keyboard shortcuts